# Recommendations for learning and getting hands-on Real Time Signal processing

Tags: discrete-signals, embedded-systems

I know this is not a technical question, but wanted to get some opinion on how to get some hands-on experience on embedded DSP / real-time signal processing

I am comfortable with DSP and wireless communications simulations in MATLAB /python and wanted to get into embedded DSP development and I'm not able to get any structured way of learning real-time DSP (I regret not taking RTSP class in my masters) . I'm proficient in C and have a very basic level knowledge in  assembly. I'm ok to buy the hardware for my learning curve.

I tried searching for any online training /course from universities which offers such class where we start writing some vector DSP code on the embedded platform (TI or ARM etc).

Any recommendations/insight into this would be highly grateful.

Thanks
Saira

Comment: Hi! This is a bit open-ended, and you're really asking for an opinion. Sadly, that doesn't fit the site's methodology well (and hence isn't allowed by the rules).

Comment: I agree @MarcusMüller . I cant ake down the post if it really doesn't fit.

Comment: Thanks @Fat32 .. I'm following a UT-Austin lab with their prescribed textbook .. I posted the links below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had taken the course at my university. So most of the materials were provided as part of it. I worked with 2 different DSPs both of which were provided at the lab.

If you are looking to buy hardware, **Real-Time Digital Signal Processing by Sen M Kuo and Bob H Lee** is a good book with implementation and architecture descriptions of TMS320C55x. It has around 9 interesting application-level implementations as well. But getting all the hardware necessary might be too much though.

Comment: went through the second edition online and it looks promising. I think the hardware they recommend in third edition is ezDSP .

Comment: I found this RTSP course from UT-Austin  which is really good and they use this textbook  " Real-Time Digital Signal Processing from MATLAB to C with the TMS320C6x DSPs "  and the UT instructor videos are on   https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaJppqXMef2ZHIKM4vpwHIAWyRmw3TtSf

Comment: Thanks @Aaquila

Comment: @Saira Great, thanks for the update!!